# Prometheus: PromQL - Adding a label to the metric

Tags: prometheus

I want to calculate sum of the metric `my_metric` by label `my_label`:

```
sum(my_metric) by (my_label)
```

As a result I get:

```
{my_label="A"}
{my_label="B"}
```

Also I want to calculate total sum of the metric:

```
sum(my_metric)
```

As a result I get the metric without labels. But what I want is:

```
{my_label="TOTAL"}
```

How can I achieve this?

My goal is to write one query like this:

```
sum(my_metric) by (my_label)
or
sum(my_metric) # add label my_label=TOTAL
```

with the result:

```
{my_label="A"}
{my_label="B"}
{my_label="TOTAL"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the label value of a PromQL query result.

However, are you using Grafana to watch your metrics ? If so, you can change the legend and print **TOTAL** instead of the metric name. You can even format the legend in order to print the metric name + a custom label.
You can find an example [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/visualization/grafana/#creating-a-prometheus-graph)